# How to get json list of files in git repository?

Tags: json, git, list, parsing

i want to get a list of files from my git repo in JSON format. Have you got any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Javascript to get the list of a user's Github repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850527/use-javascript-to-get-the-list-of-a-users-github-repositories)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all file names from a Github repo through the Github API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022016/get-all-file-names-from-a-github-repo-through-the-github-api)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for but

```
$ git ls-files | jq -MRn '[inputs]'
```

will generate a JSON array with whatever `git ls-files` returns e.g.

```
[
  ".gitignore",
  ".gitmodules",
  ".travis.yml",
  "AUTHORS",
  "COPYING",
  "ChangeLog",
  "Dockerfile"
]
```

Comment: To correctly handle filenames which contain newlines: `git ls-files -z | jq -Rs 'split("\u0000")'`.